# How to compare every value in a Pandas dataframe to all the next values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am learning Pandas and I am moving my python code to Pandas. I want to compare every value with the next values using a sub. So the first with the second etc.. The second with the third but not with the first because I already did that. In python I use two nested loops over a list:

```
sub match_values (a, b):
  #do some stuff...

l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
length = len(l)

for i in range (1, length):
  for j in range (i, length):  # starts from i, not from the start!
     if match_values(l[i], l[j]):
        #do some stuff...
```

How do I do a similar technique in Pandas when my list is a column in a dataframe? Do I simply reference every value like before or is there a clever "vector-style" way to do this fast and efficient?

Thanks in advance,

Jo

Comment: What `sub match_values (a, b)` is supposed to do?

Comment: I want to to linguistic identity matching. It does some preprocessing on the two strings like removing special characters and then it calculates the levenshtein ratio. If that is smaller than .70 it returns True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check this ? It provides an output in the form of a list for each row after comparing the values.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np 
>>> val = [16,19,15,19,15]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'val': val})
>>> df
   val
0   16
1   19
2   15
3   19
4   15
>>> 
>>> 
>>> df['match'] = df.apply(lambda x: [ (1 if (x['val'] == df.loc[idx, 'val']) else 0) for idx in range(x.name+1, len(df)) ], axis=1)  
>>> df
   val         match
0   16  [0, 0, 0, 0]
1   19     [0, 1, 0]
2   15        [0, 1]
3   19           [0]
4   15            []
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'd like to compare the 16 with the 19, 15, 19 (the first value with the second, the thirth, fourth... and then the second with the third, fourth etc... I think this code compares two values and not a value with every value "under" it?

Comment: Actually, it does. For every `df['val']`, `df['val'].shift(-1)` is the value `under` it. 1 is assigned for the match. You may notice that for last row, `match` is 0 because there is no value after it.

Comment: i am sorry if i get it wrong but it seems to me it is still not a nested loop. It compares value 0 with 1, value 1 with 2, value 2 with 3 and 3 with 4. Right? I need to compare value 1 with 2, then with 3, then with 4. Then value 2 with 3 and with 4 and then value 3 with value 4.

Comment: Sorry I misread the question. Please check the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, vector comparison as pandas is built on Numpy:

```
df['columnname'] > 5
```

This will result in a Boolean array. If you also want to return the actually part of the dataframe:

```
df[df['columnname'] > 5]
```